# FFmpeg support for repeating last audiosample and videoframe when input stream stops or delivers corrupt data?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, live-streaming, transcoding, avconv

Our goal is to deliver on-the-fly packaged Live HLS and Mpeg DASH from a mpeg-ts multicast source.

We use ffmpeg to transcode/mux the mpeg-ts input to ISMV (smooth streaming format) and transfer via http to [Unified Origin](http://docs.unified-streaming.com/introduction/index.html) running Apache.

What we want to achieve is a constant ISMV stream to Unified Origin regardless of input stability.

We have tried separating decoding and encoding by having two FFMPEG processes:

1. Decodes "rawvideo" and "s16be" (audio) and sends to two python developed buffers that have the ability to repeat the last frame/sample if no input is provided.
2. Uses the two buffer as input (over tcp) and encode/mux to ISMV.

This solution seems to solve the stability issue, but synchronising a/v and knowing when to provide repeated frames instead of live frames seems to be impossible. We have so far assumed that ffmpeg requires a continuous input stream to produce any output if the input is not or can not be provided, output stops.

Does FFmpeg have built in functionality for repeating a/v when the input stream either stops delivering data or delivers corrupt data?

Is there any industry standard way to deal with unstable input?